# Opening an Excel File through C# and writing data

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, export-to-excel

[image]

i have an application which tries to open an Excel file stored in a specific location and write some data content to it .

Here is my code :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                //String inputFile = @"D:\Excel\Input.xlsx";

                Excel.Application oXL = new Excel.Application();


#if DEBUG
                oXL.Visible = true;
                oXL.DisplayAlerts = true;
#else
                oXL.Visible = false; 
                oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
#endif


                //Open a New Excel File

              // Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

             Excel.Workbook   oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users/diwesh/Downloads/WriteExcel/WriteExcel/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Debug/Input.xlsx");

               // Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(@".\Input.xlsx");


                Excel._Worksheet oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;




                oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";  
                oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Percentage(%)"; // Here 1 is the rowIndex and 2 is the columnIndex.
                oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = txt_Name.Text;


                //Format the Header row to make it Bold and blue
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").Interior.Color = Color.SkyBlue;
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B1").Font.Bold = true;
                //Set the column widthe of Column A and Column B to 20
                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B12").ColumnWidth = 20;

                oSheet.get_Range("A1", "B3").Font.Bold = true;

               // String ReportFile = @"D:\Excel\Output.xls";
                String ReportFile = @".\Excel\Output.xls";
                oWB.SaveAs(ReportFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault,
                                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                        false,
                                        false,
                                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                                        Type.Missing,
                                        Type.Missing,
                                        Type.Missing,
                                        Type.Missing,
                                        Type.Missing);


                oXL.Quit();

                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oWB);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oXL);

                oSheet = null;
                oWB = null;
                oXL = null;
                GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                String errorMessage = "Error reading the Excel file : " + ex.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                //MessageBox.Show("Thank you the excel data has been saved");
            }

        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txt_Name.Text = "Diwesh";
        }
    }
}
```

Trouble 1 : `Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(@".\Input.xlsx");`

This does not find the "Input.xlsx" and opens up just the application unless i give it a full path like :

```
Excel.Workbook oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users/diwesh/Downloads/WriteExcel/WriteExcel/WindowsFormsApplication1/bin/Debug/Input.xlsx");
```

Trouble 2 : It always ends up entering the Exception loop .

Please help .

This is how the form looks like :

[image]

Comment: As a kindly suggestion: Use a library like EPPLUS to read / write excel files. Way faster, way more resilient and much less headache during development

Comment: @ChristianSauer : Thanks for the advice . The data to be saved is not that huge. So i avoided using an extra library. This code works just fine without any delay. The only troubles i am encountering are as listed if you can help with that .

Comment: Remove temporarily the try/catch block and see on what line exactly you get the exception. I believe it is not the line `oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(...`

Comment: @VDonhal : I did try that and found the exception occurs at "oWB.SaveAs"

Comment: @VDohnal:Exception details : Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\Users\diwesh\Documents\Excel\4BCD5420'. There are several possible reasons:



• The file name or path does not exist.

Comment: You should use `.xlsx` extension if your default save format is not set to Office 2003. Also it is just OK to write `targetWB.SaveAs(fileName)` instead of your long list of `Type.Missing`. Also check your version of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assemblies, should be the last one, which is 14 I think.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a relative path, have you tried to create your path like this:

```
String example01 = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
String resultPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(
            System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(example01),
            "test.xlsx"
            );
```

This is assuming that your excel file is in the same directory as your application is.